# HTML Anchor Button Problems

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to create a button towards the bottom of my website.

Here's my HTML

```
<center><a href="#" id="btn1" class="btn1">
    View 
</a></center>
```

Here's my CSS.

```
.btn1 {
    margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
    color: white;
    background: #ED7836;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

When I try creating the button, it seems to ignore my set margins and align itself right at the very bottom of the page.

[Bottom of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq1k5.png)

When I try to set its positioning to absolute and putting left: 50% it seems to position itself at a weird location that is not in the centre.

```
.btn1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
    color: white;
    background: #ED7836;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[Doesn't align in the centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AoC3.png)

Thank you.

Comment: add: transform: translateX(-50%);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `transform: translate(-50%, 0%);` to make it in exact center.

```
.btn1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
    color: white;
    background: #ED7836;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Without origin, like you said it looks like this(which is the way it should actually be)
[image: example1] https://jsfiddle.net/z5qo8yaj/

You need to use translate to move it about it's origin(by half of it's length)
After adding *translate*
[image: example 2]
https://jsfiddle.net/h1qzdoLm/